# Proper alignment of labels in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I don't like vertical labels for Y axis. Thus, I tend to do:

```
plt.ylabel('horizontal label', 
      rotation=0)
```

Which results in a nice label:

[image: one-line label]

However, if the required label contains more than one lines, the results is suboptimal:

```
plt.ylabel('horizontal\nmultiline label', 
     rotation=0, ha='right')
```

[image: Multiline label]

Changing to `ha='left'` doesn't do the right job

[image: bad alignment]

Is there a simple way to achieve this:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`multialignment`](http://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html?highlight=text#matplotlib.text.Text.set_multialignment) (`ma=`) parameter:

> `set_multialignment(align)`
>
> Set the alignment for multiple lines layout. The layout of the bounding box of all the lines is determined by the `horizontalalignment` and `verticalalignment` properties, but the multiline text within that box can be
>
> ACCEPTS: [‘left’ | ‘right’ | ‘center’ ]

```
plt.ylabel('horizontal\nmultiline label', ha='right', va='center', ma='left',
           rotation=0)
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `set_label_coords()` method of the `ax.yaxis` to define the (x, y) location of the label. You'll also probably want to use the `va` keyword argument as well. Putting them together you'd have:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_ylabel('horizontal\nmultiline label', rotation=0, ha='left', va='center')
ax.yaxis.set_label_coords(-0.25, 0.5)
```

Which should output this:

[image: horizontal_label.png]

Adjust the values passed to `set_label_coords()` as desired.